# Why did Kingsley Shacklebolt replace Pius Thicknesse as the Minister for Magic after the war?

Tags: harry-potter, ministry-of-magic

After the end of the second wizarding war (ultimate defeat of Lord Voldemort), why was Kingsley named the new Minister for Magic? I recall that Pius Thicknesse was the Minister for Magic in book 7?  Why wasn't he allowed to continue with his tenure as the Minister for Magic? Why was Kingsley chosen to be the new Minister after the war instead?

Comment: It's been said to you before a few times but can you try and use better titles more in line with what you are actually asking. You have decent titles as questions in the post that can easily be made into the title or just use something like what another user has edited in.

Answer (score 38):

Per [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ministers-for-magic), Pius Thicknesse was removed from office after it was discovered that he had been under the Imperius Curse for the whole time he'd been Minister for Magic. Shacklebolt then took over as a "caretaker" MfM (while the Death Eaters and Voldemort's other followers were being rounded up) and the subsequent election resulted in his being elected.

> **Pius Thicknesse**
>   **1997 - 1998**
>   Omitted from most official records, as he was under the Imperius Curse for his entire term of office, and unconscious of anything that he was doing.
>
> **Kingsley Shacklebolt**
>   **1998 - present**
>   Oversaw the capture of Death Eaters and Voldemort supporters following the death of Lord Voldemort. Initially named as ‘caretaker Minister’, Shacklebolt was subsequently elected to the office.
>
> <sub><sup>[Pottermore: *Ministers for Magic* By J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ministers-for-magic)</sup></sub>

As to why people voted for him, there are a considerable number of points in his favour. He's described as an "*Exceptionally skilled duellist and Auror*", was a known fighter of Voldemort, was a safe pair of hands (with Ministry experience) to be made MfM pro-tem and was one of the [Sacred Twenty-Eight](https://www.pottermore.com/features/who-are-the-sacred-twenty-eight) pureblood families.

Comment: There's a lot of parallels with Barty Crouch, Sr. who was also widely considered one of the favourite candidates for Minister for Magic after the first Wizarding War, mostly due to his experience in Magical Law Enforcement (if I recall correctly he was head of the Auror office). People want the safety and security that somebody who actively fought Voldemort provides immediately after a war. I suspect that, historically, similar things can be seen in the real world.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to link to the [JKR-written page about the Sacred Twenty-Eight](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/pure-blood) rather than the fan written one?

Answer (score 11):

From Pottermore:

> **Kingsley Shacklebolt**
>   **1998 - present**
>   Oversaw the capture of Death Eaters and Voldemort supporters following the death of Lord Voldemort. Initially named as ‘caretaker Minister’, Shacklebolt was subsequently elected to the office.

It is not uncommon after the end of a war for war heroes to be elevated to office, by appointment or election, and in this case it was both. It would make sense to appoint an Auror or member of the Order of the Phoenix to the post to put the public's mind at ease. Of the surviving Aurors/Order Members, Kingsley was likely the one most palatable to those making the offer. Kingsley had a great deal of experience, and took a leadership role during the Battle of Hogwarts. Other members either did not want the job, were too injured to perform the necessary duties, or flat out too young.

As for Thicknesse, it's not hard to see why he did not continue. First, he had been compromised; he was a puppet of Voldemort from day one. Even after the Imperius had been lifted, no one would look at him quite the same again. The public would have a *very* hard time trusting him. He is even omitted from official records as even *having* the post to begin with, as he was put in place by Voldemort after he had taken over.

Given his disappearance afterwards, even if the post was offered, he would likely refuse. The limelight was the last thing he wanted at that point, and disappeared to live out his life in quiet ignominy.

Answer (score 5):

Because [Pius Thicknesse had been working for Voldemort](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40835/19561) during the Second Wizarding War.

> "All right, all right, we'll have time for a cozy catch-up later," roared Moody over the hubbub, and silence fell in the kitchen. Moody dropped his sacks at his feet and turned to Harry, "As Dedalus probably told you, we had to abandon Plan A. Pius Thicknesse has gone over, which gives us a big problem."
>
> <sub>–*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, chapter 4: "The Seven Potters", by J.K. Rowling</sub>

Of course, he was under the influence of an Imperius Curse.

> "My Lord, I have good news on that score. I have — with difficulty,
>   and after great effort — succeeded in placing an Imperius Curse upon Pius Thicknesse." Many of those sitting around Yaxley looked impressed; his neighbor, Dolohov, a man with a long, twisted face, clapped him on the back.
>
> "It is a start," said Voldemort. "But Thicknesse is only one man. Scrimgeour must be surrounded by our people before I act. One failed attempt on the Minister’s life will set me back a long way."
>
> <sub>–*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, chapter 1: "The Dark Lord Ascending", by J.K. Rowling</sub>

Having a Minister for Magic under the influence of an Imperius Curse is as if the one casting the curse was in office instead – Yaxley, a Death Eater.

So it wasn't really Pius Thicknesse who was Minister for Magic.

> **Pius Thicknesse**
>   **1997 - 1998**
>   Omitted from most official records, as he was under the Imperius Curse for his entire term of office, and unconscious of anything that he was doing.
>
> <sub>–*Pottermore*, "Ministers for Magic", by J.K. Rowling</sub>

As evidenced by his entry on *Pottermore*, his term of office is almost considered to not have happened at all.

---

Besides that, the question would've remained how much of his actions were due to the Imperius Curse, and if that Curse had fully worn off. He wouldn't have had any authority left and would not have been fully trusted.

Answer (score 1):

To address why specifically Kingsley, there is the following dialogue between Kingsley and Lee Jordan on *Potterwatch* on the night that Harry, Ron, and Hermione get captured (my emphasis):

> "And what would you say, Royal, to those listeners who reply that in
>   these dangerous times, it should be 'Wizards first'?" asked Lee.
>
> "I'd say that it's one short step from 'Wizards first'to 'Purebloods
>   first,' and then to 'Death Eaters,'" replied Kingsley. "We're all
>   human, aren't we? Every human life is worth the same, and worth
>   saving."
>
> "Excellently put, Royal, **and you've got my vote for Minister of Magic
>   if we ever get out of this mess," said Lee.**

When they did in fact get out of the mess a mere month or so later, those who had listened to *Potterwatch* may well have remembered this interview when it came time to appoint a new minister.