# What happened to Pius Thicknesse after his misfortunate term as the Minister?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters, character-development, unforgivable-curse, ministry-of-magic

From *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* and *Pottermore*, we know that [Pius Thicknesse has been sacked and replaced by Kingsley Shacklebolt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195066/why-did-kingsley-shacklebolt-replace-pius-thicknesse-as-the-minister-for-magic-a), who made a successful Minister of Magic. But what happened to Pius after the war?

From *Pottermore* (["Ministers of Magic"](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ministers-for-magic)):

> **Pius Thicknesse**
>   **1997 - 1998**
>   Omitted from most official records, as he was under the Imperius Curse for his entire term of office, and unconscious of anything that he was doing.

Answer (score 6):

## Unclear, but he won’t have been convicted as he was Imperiused.

Though it’s never explicitly stated, it seems likely that Thicknesse would have survived the battle, as his death is never mentioned, and as the Order knew he was under the Imperius Curse, it was unlikely they’d particularly want to kill him rather than just stop him from fighting. There’s no real information about what he did after the battle. The one thing that can be reasoned from what is known is that, presuming he did indeed survive, he wouldn’t have been convicted over his actions as Minister. The Order knew he’d been Imperiused, which would mean Kingsley knew as well.

> “The official version of Scrimgeour’s murder is that he resigned; he has been replaced by Pius Thicknesse, who is under the Imperius Curse.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 11 (The Bribe)*</sup></sub>

Avery was able to get himself acquitted from his crimes by claiming he was under the Imperius Curse, showing that being Imperiused is considered a reason for acquittal.

> “Avery – from what I’ve heard he wormed his way out of trouble by saying he’d been acting under the Imperius Curse – he’s still at large.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 27 (Padfoot Returns)*</sup></sub>

Once someone is known to be under the Imperius Curse, they’re not convicted. After the first war with the Dark Lord, the Ministry of Magic had to figure out who had been Imperiused and who hadn’t been, so they could charge the people who willingly acted but not those forced into it.

> “Years back, there were a lot of witches and wizards being controlled by the Imperius Curse,’ said Moody, and Harry knew he was talking about the days in which Voldemort had been all-powerful. ‘Some job for the Ministry, trying to sort out who was being forced to act, and who was acting of their own free will.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 14 (The Unforgivable Curses)*</sup></sub>

Thicknesse was known by the Order to have been Imperiused, and Kingsley, one of the Order’s members, became Minister and oversaw the efforts to arrest the remaining of the Dark Lord’s supporters. Once Thicknesse survived, he wouldn’t have been convicted - though it’s unclear what did happen to him and it’s never mentioned what (if any) life he led after being Imperiused.

Answer (score 3):

**We don't know**
It was never explicitly stated that he died in the books so we can assume that he continued his life after he was removed from being under the Imperius curse.

> Aberforth Stunning Rookwood, Arthur and Percy flooring Thicknesse 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

That was the last time in the book that Thicknesse was mentioned. We see that 
Arthur/Percy didn't kill him, but merely disabled him from fighting for awhile and possibly knocked him out for the remainder of the Battle of Hogwarts which was nearly over. Since he was (probably) out of the line of fire for the remainder of the Battle its probable he survived and lived out the rest of his life.

**In the movies he does die**
 Here is a clip showing his death.